# unused value warning: C vs C++ using gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Is it possible to make *gcc* handle unused-value warnings for C like like *g++* handles them for C++? For instructions like `p && ++*p;` in C, there is a warning, but not for C++. Setting `-wno-unused-value` is not really a solution, since it would also remove useful warnings (like in line 2 below). Example:

`$ (gcc --version|head -1; ls -l qwe.*; cat qwe.x; echo $sep; gcc -c -O2 -Wall qwe.c; echo $sep; g++ -c -O2 -Wall qwe.cc) 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /'`

```
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tml tml    5 Jul 23 10:12 qwe.c -> qwe.x
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tml tml    5 Jul 23 10:12 qwe.cc -> qwe.x
-rw-r--r-- 1 tml tml 1384 Jul 23 10:49 qwe.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 tml tml   55 Jul 23 10:49 qwe.x
void g(int *p) { p && ++*p; }
void f(int *p) { *p+5; }
-------------------------------------------
qwe.c: In function ‘g’:
qwe.c:1:20: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
 void g(int *p) { p && ++*p; }
                    ^
qwe.c: In function ‘f’:
qwe.c:2:18: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
 void f(int *p) { *p+5; }
                  ^
-------------------------------------------
qwe.cc: In function ‘void f(int*)’:
qwe.cc:2:20: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 void f(int *p) { *p+5; }
                    ^
```

Comment: *gcc* and *g++* are basically the same compiler as far as compile time warnings are concerned, difference is between C/C++. I edited the question to reflect this, feel free to roll the edit back if you feel I went too far.

Comment: @EdHeal The code in question is most likely to intended to be an MVCE, to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @marton-l-toth I think I did something wrong in my testing. I deleted my comment until I can figure out what I *did* test...

Comment: If you change the code to `if (p) ++*p;`, does that change anything?

Comment: @hyde: in that case there is no warning (of course, otherwise this warning would be completely unusable :) ) ; but -- as you correctly noted above -- this was intended to be a minimal example, and sometimes (esp. when using preprocessor) I want to "keep it an expression".

Comment: Are you sure _g++_ does not give you warning? Because it does in my case...

Comment: @lapk: could you tell me which gcc version you tried with (I was using 4.9.2)

Comment: @marton-l-toth my bad, i misread your post. maybe, you are right. let me double check. P.S. You are right, they do give different warnings. I misread your OP, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually remove them by casting them to void.

```
void f(int *p) { (void)*p+5; }
```

But there is a reason for these warnings. These don't actually do anything. There is no side affects happening here. So the result of calling this function is the same as not calling the function.

Calling the function `f(&x)` is likely to be optimized away completely by a reasonable compiler.

Comment: I suspect they wanted to hide the warning for `p && ++*p;`  , but they provided `*p+5` as an example of a warning that they still want to see